# Topic "Troubleshooting" no response inside browser console

Tags: sapui5

I cannot get this to work as stated in the UI5 documentation topic [*Troubleshooting*](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/eadd60ae907646bbb838866566b23182) for browser developer tools.

I already typed the code but I see no response.

> ```js
> myView=sap.ui.getCore().byId("HeapOfShards---app").
> myView.byId("myButton").
> ```

[image: No response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue 1

When pasting code snippet from the documentation, you need to omit the full stop (`.`).
Otherwise, the console will think that the expression is not complete, hence, no response.

But just omitting the full stop will lead to an error that `myView` is undefined. See *Issue 2*.

## Issue 2

Since UI5 1.61.0, the component in the sample code (`id="HeapOfShards"`) gets an additional auto-prefixed ID from the parent ComponentContainer (`id="container"`). Therefore, when accessing the root view via the global ID like in the topic, the ID of the ComponentContainer needs to be prepended:

```js
myView = sap.ui.getCore().byId("container-HeapOfShards---app");
myView.byId("myButton");
```

This is clearly a documentation issue that needs to be fixed. **Update:** It's [fixed](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2471#issuecomment-494690406) now.

#### Why it didn't work

In 1.61, the sample code for *Troubleshooting* moved from creating the ComponentContainer via inline-script to creating it declaratively via the module `sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport`.<sup>[commit](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/a46e03745492fe55f3cd666f120dc775406b0dcd#diff-88747be5c34cf41cb50b941dfaec670f)</sup>

The reason why `.byId("HeapOfShards---app")` suddenly failed is that ComponentSupport sets several settings beforehand when creating the ComponentContainer, among which the `autoPrefixId` gets `true` by default. <sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/eb3513d3097aa410627e78a785029791935f4847/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport.js#L134-L164)</sup>

When creating the ComponentContainer directly **without** the ComponentSupport,  `autoPrefixId` is `false` by default which is why it was all fine in previous versions.